# Unreadable Text when starting Alloy Analyzer on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, alloy

I try to start [*Alloy Analyzer*](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/download.html) on

```
Windows 7 Enterprise
Service Pack 1
```

and get the folowing error

```
D:\alloy>where java
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe

D:\alloy>java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

D:\alloy>java -jar alloy4.2.jar
Okt 10, 2015 11:14:02 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0
x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

I can avoid the error message when I create the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs` manually or start alloy as administrator. But nevertheless a windows with unreadable characters opens

[image: alloy windows]

I tried *alloy4.jar* but that shows the same behavior.

I tried the latest version of *alloy* (*alloy4.2_2015-02-22.jar*) and it has the same behaviour and I get the additional error messages

```
D:\alloy>java -jar alloy4.2_2015-02-22.jar
Okt 10, 2015 11:14:02 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0
x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Failed to load: minisat.dll
Failed to load: minisatprover.dll
Failed to load: lingeling.dll
Failed to load: glucose.dll
Failed to load: cryptominisat.dll
```

How can I start *alloy* correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the cause of the error. 
The font that was configured after the first startup was *3 of 9 barcode*. This can be changed by clicking on this menu item (Options->Font) and selecting an appropriate font, e.g. Arial.

[image]